# l20n: server-side node resolveValues error

Tags: javascript, node.js, l20n

I can't run example code from the l20n-node Github page without errors.

```
import { Env, fetchResource } from 'l20n';

const env = new Env('en-US', fetchResource);
const ctx = env.createContext(['locales/{locale}.l20n']);
const langs = [
  {code: 'es-ES'},
  {code: 'en-US'}
];

ctx.resolveValues(langs, ['foo', 'bar']).then(
  ([foo, bar]) => console.log(foo, bar));
```

First of all it uses ES6 import syntax, that is not actually applied by node.
I edited it a bit:

```
var Env =  require('l20n').Env;
var fetchResource = require('l20n').fetchResource;
var env = new Env('ru', fetchResource);
```

But there is another problem: `function resolveValues` does not exist. 
Does anyone have well-implemented node.js snippet for l20n? Need it badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a documentation bug, I'm sorry for the trouble.  The Node support is experimental and the `Env` API is internal and it changed without a corresponding change to the docs.  The documentation is now [up-to-date](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/commit/c8bea28044c054db0accda5701ff36e13f9476e9):

```
const L20n = require('l20n');
const langs = [
  {code: 'es-ES'},
  {code: 'en-US'}
];

// fetchResource is node-specific, Env isn't
const env = new L20n.Env(L20n.fetchResource);

// helpful for debugging
env.addEventListener('*', e => console.log(e));

// contexts are immutable;  if langs change a new context must be created
const ctx = env.createContext(langs, ['./locales/{locale}.l20n']);

// pass string ids or tuples of [id, args]
ctx.formatValues('foo', ['bar', {baz: 'Baz'}]).then(values => {
  // values is an array of resolved translations
  console.log(values);
});

// -> ['Foo en español', 'Bar only exists in English']
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a 'case study' tutorial for Node.js + Polymer + L20n integration.
[Tutorial: solution for node.js / Polymer i18n based on L20n library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677198/tutorial-solution-for-node-js-polymer-i18n-based-on-l20n-library/35677199#35677199)